# Missing Right Parentheses

Tags: sql

I am an end user who uses Business Objects to create reports in free hand SQL. I have been working with some code for the past three hours and keep getting the error msg "Missing Right Parenthese". I have looked at this code so long that now I'm not sure if the error was highlighted hat I would see it Please help. The code is below:

```
SELECT   
decode(usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts') Project,
      nvl(Year1.TotAmt,0) "2007", nvl(Year2.TotAmt,0) "2008", nvl(Year3.TotAmt,0) "2009", 
      nvl(Year4.TotAmt,0) "2010", nvl(Year5.TotAmt,0) "2011",nvl(Year6.TotAmt,0) "2012",
nvl(Year7.TotAmt,0) "2013"
from payment p,
--- Year 1
   (select sum(p.payamount) TotAmt, (usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts') Project, 
           max(to_char(paydate,'yyyy')) Year
   from   payment p
   where  trunc(p.paydate) between @prompt('1.Enter Start Date For Period in FIRST Year','D',,,) and 
                                    @prompt('2.Enter End Date For Period in FIRST Year','D',,,) and 
          p.CLASSCODE  NOT IN  ('NONGIF', 'PCRED') and
          p.usercode1 in ('005','016','021','031','033','041','044')
   group by 
         decode(usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts')) Year1,
--- Year 2
(select sum(p.payamount) TotAmt, (usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts') Project, 
           max(to_char(paydate,'yyyy')) Year
   from   payment p
   where  trunc(p.paydate-366) between @prompt('1.Enter Start Date For Period in FIRST Year','D',,,) and 
                                        @prompt('2.Enter End Date For Period in FIRST Year','D',,,) and 
          p.CLASSCODE  NOT IN  ('NONGIF', 'PCRED') and
          p.usercode1 in ('005','016','021','031','033','041','044')
   group by 
         decode(usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts')) Year2,
--- Year 3
   (select sum(p.payamount) TotAmt, (usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts') Project, 
           max(to_char(paydate,'yyyy')) Year
   from   payment p
   where  trunc(p.paydate-731) between @prompt('1.Enter Start Date For Period in FIRST Year','D',,,) and 
                                        @prompt('2.Enter End Date For Period in FIRST Year','D',,,) and 
          p.CLASSCODE  NOT IN  ('NONGIF', 'PCRED') and
          p.usercode1 in ('005','016','021','031','033','041','044')
   group by 
         decode(usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts')) Year3,
--- Year 4
    (select sum(p.payamount) TotAmt, (usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts') Project, 
           max(to_char(paydate,'yyyy')) Year
   from   payment p
   where  trunc(p.paydate-1096) between @prompt('1.Enter Start Date For Period in FIRST Year','D',,,) and 
                                        @prompt('2.Enter End Date For Period in FIRST Year','D',,,) and 
          p.CLASSCODE  NOT IN  ('NONGIF', 'PCRED') and
           p.usercode1 in ('005','016','021','031','033','041','044')
  group by 
         decode(usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts')) Year4,
--- Year 5
  (select sum(p.payamount) TotAmt, (usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts') Project, 
           max(to_char(paydate,'yyyy')) Year
   from   payment p
   where  trunc(p.paydate-1461) between @prompt('1.Enter Start Date For Period in FIRST Year','D',,,) and 
                                        @prompt('2.Enter End Date For Period in FIRST Year','D',,,) and 
          p.CLASSCODE  NOT IN  ('NONGIF', 'PCRED') and
           p.usercode1 in ('005','016','021','031','033','041','044')
  group by 
         decode(usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts')) Year5,

--- Year 6
     (select sum(p.payamount) TotAmt, (usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts') Project, 
           max(to_char(paydate,'yyyy')) Year
   from   payment p
   where  trunc(p.paydate-1826) between @prompt('1.Enter Start Date For Period in FIRST Year','D',,,) and 
                                    @prompt('2.Enter End Date For Period in FIRST Year','D',,,) and 
          p.CLASSCODE  NOT IN  ('NONGIF', 'PCRED') and
           p.usercode1 in ('005','016','021','031','033','041','044')
   group by 
         decode(usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts')) Year6,

--- Year 7
   (select sum(p.payamount) TotAmt, (usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts') Project, 
           max(to_char(paydate,'yyyy')) Year
   from   payment p
   where  trunc(p.paydate-2192) between @prompt('1.Enter Start Date For Period in FIRST Year','D',,,) and 
                                    @prompt('2.Enter End Date For Period in FIRST Year','D',,,) and 
          p.CLASSCODE  NOT IN  ('NONGIF', 'PCRED') and
          p.usercode1 in ('005','016','021','031','033','041','044')
    group by 
         decode(usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts')) Year7



where  p.paydate between to_date ('10/01/2007','mm/dd/yyyy') and 
                          to_date ('12/31/2013','mm/dd/yyyy') and 
       p.CLASSCODE  NOT IN  ('NONGIF', 'PCRED') and
        p.usercode1 in ('005','016','021','031','033','041','044') and
       decode(usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts') = Year1.Project(+) and
       decode(usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts') = Year2.Project(+) and
       decode(usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts') = Year3.Project(+) and
      decode(usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts') = Year4.Project(+) and
       decode(usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts')= Year5.Project(+) and
     decode(usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts') = Year6.Project(+)  and


     decode(usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts') = Year7.Project(+) 



group by 
decode(usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts'),
       Year1.TotAmt, Year2.TotAmt, Year3.TotAmt, Year4.TotAmt, Year5.TotAmt, Year6.TotAmt,Year7.TotAmt
order by 
      decode(usercode1, '005','Major Gifts','016','Major Gifts','021','Major Gifts','031','Major Gifts',
                  '033','Major Gifts','041','Major Gifts',
                  '044','Major Gifts')
```

Comment: You might want to... start over. And check that your query compiles after every small change, so you know the instant it is wrong. This is too much for anyone to want to read.

Comment: use formatter that understands Oracle SQL. It can detect syntax error. There are a few online formatters that is capable of parsing PL/SQL.

Answer (score 2):

In the Year subqueries, there's code that looks like `(usercode1, ...) Project`. You need a `decode` in front of each of them.

As an aside, I'd recommend getting yourself a text editor (such as gvim) that does bracket matching so that you can more easily identify these problems.

Comment: That and do a better job at indentation.

Comment: He can't help that, since it's generated by Business Objects. I've never seen a single tool generate nicely formatted SQL.